# Simulating a WebView from an Android Service

Tags: android, cookies, android-service, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am creating an app that allows a user to login to a website, and then automatically checks every few minutes for new information that is only available when you are logged in.

To accomplish this, I present a WebView that the user logs in to, and once logged in, I hide it and load pages in the background to fetch the information. (I pull the loaded content with JavaScript).

The issue is, I want to move this logic into a service that can run in the background indefinitely. Ideally I could just use HttpGet requests, but I'm not sure how I could pass the cookies along.

Is there a way to use an HttpPost to post to the login page, and then just copy the cookies from that over to the HttpGet for reuse later? I do not have server access to the website, I am just making a convenience app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally I could just use HttpGet requests, but I'm not sure how I could pass the cookies along.

That will happen automatically, so long as you are using the same `HttpClient` instance.

Comment: You're joking. I'm not used to Java, that is wonderful. Thank you!